# Split string at numbers and place into array, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, math

So for the string `x1v4xy6` it should become `['x',1,'v',4,'xy',6]`

Preferably it can split operands as well, so `x+4y-5zy` becomes `[1,x,+,4,y,-,5,zy]`.

Spliting on individual characters would have problems when a number is more than one digit.

I tried this

```
c= a.split(/(?<=\d)(?=[A-Za-z])/)
```

it works sometimes, however 
2x+y+3z becomes ["2", "x+y+3", "z"]", the 3 failed to split properly

Comment: You received a downvote because A> you didn't show any code attempt we can work with, and B> your requirements are unclear. `+` can't appear alone in an array; only a symbol `:+` or a string `'+'` can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [scan](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-scan) instead of [split](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-split):

```
pattern = /(?:[+-]|[0-9]+|[a-z]+)/

>> '2x+3y-4zy'.scan(pattern)
=> ["2", "x", "+", "3", "y", "-", "4", "zy"]

>> '2x+y+3z'.scan(pattern)
=> ["2", "x", "+", "y", "+", "3", "z"]
```

Note: `+` and `-` are either strings or symbols, they **cannot** appear alone. I thought `send` method would help you, eg: `1.send(:+, 2) => 3`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This was works pretty good, however it deletes any slashes or brackets in the original input, is there a way to keep those things during the scan/split

Comment: Please give me your example with `slashes/brackets` and your expected output